# Integration of dhtmlXGrid with Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, dhtmlx

Does anybody has some experience with [`dhtmlxGrid`](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/index.shtml?mn%20dhtmlXGrid) component from dhtmlx ? I had bought PRO version few days ago and i am now feeling kind a lost, because i cannot connect it with my Backbone models. And support from them is sort of silent...

I need this, because i need to monitor for changes in those models and update grid with that change.

Best approach would be some *data adapter*, which is used by grid to get data for rows. So i could read there directly from model without duplicating anything to another JSON object. And when model changes i would tell grid to invalidate rows by ID and it will read data again from that *data adapter*.

I tried using `dhtmlXDataStore`, but it's lacking documentation and i cannot make it work. Do you have any other ideas ?

Comment: You *bought* a license and they are not responding to your support questions? That's messed.

Comment: Yeah exactly. I though it will have some professional level, but it's nearly 24 hours with no response :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old post, just wanted to say that using the dhtmlx datastore is a good approach.  Any change made to the datastore is automatically pushed to the grid.

Also there are all sorts of event handlers which can be added to both the datastore and the grid.  And there are APIs to change the datastore.  Dhtmlx is pretty amazing.

I've been using dhtmlx for more than a year now and I have found there are ways to everything I've needed it to do.